# How can one register a Direct2D custom effect that has variable numbers of inputs?

Tags: directx, direct2d

I am making custom effects with Direct2D, based on [Microsoft Learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/custom-effects). The problem is that, I wanted to make a Direct2D effect which support a variable input count, like [Direct2D Composite Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/composite), while the XML registration string used for `ID2D1Factory1::RegisterEffectFromString` seemed to take fixed `<Input>` properties. What should be done in XML registration string?

My XML is almost the same as one from [Microsoft Learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/custom-effects). Still I will provide mine.

```
    auto xml_AxisRotation = XML(
        <?xml version='1.0'?>
        <Effect>
            <!--System Properties-->
            <Property name='DisplayName' type='string' value='MultiInput Effect'/>
            <Property name='Author' type='string' value='Nan_ok'/>
            <Property name='Category' type='string' value='None'/>
            <Property name='Description' type='string' value='asdfasdfasdf'/>
            <Inputs>
                <Input name='Source1'/>
                <Input name='Source2'/>
                //...?
            </Inputs>
            <!--Custom Properties go here-->
            <Property name='Mode' type='int32'>
                <Property name='DisplayName' type='string' value='Mode'/>
                <Property name='Default' type='int32' value='1'/>
            </Property>
        </Effect>
    );
```

I once deliberately omitted the whole `<Input>` part, but it failed to perform; `E_INVALIDARG` has been returned.

Comment: Have you tried `<Inputs minimum='0' maximum='9999' />`

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but this fails with HRESULT code 0x80070490. Instead, `<Inputs minimum='0' maximum='9999'> </Inputs>` works. Anyway, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The XML registration and actual Direct2D effect's input taking worked differently. By proper implementing `ID2D1EffectImpl::SetGraph` and calling `ID2D1Effect::SetInputCount`, I was able to set variable numbers of target.

It seemed ok to leave `<Inputs>` with no `<Input>` property. here is my XML example.

```
    auto xml_AxisRotation = XML(
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <Effect>
        <!--System Properties-->
        <Property name='DisplayName' type='string' value='MultiInput Effect'/>
        <Property name='Author' type='string' value='Nan_o'/>
        <Property name='Category' type='string' value='None'/>
        <Property name='Description' type='string' value='asdfasdfasdf'/>
        <Inputs> </Inputs> <!--Leaving like this is ok-->
        <!--Custom Properties go here-->
        <Property name='Mode' type='int32'>
            <Property name='DisplayName' type='string' value='Mode'/>
            <Property name='Default' type='int32' value='1'/>
        </Property>
    </Effect>
);
```